# Add image and title to the lock screen media controls

Tags: ios, audio, cordova, lockscreen

I'm close to submitting an audio app that "plays podcast in a playlist" to the Apple store for IOS 7.

I'm using PhoneGap 3.0 and I was able to make it all work except when it comes to adding the title of the audio and the corresponding image to the Lock Screen.

How do you add the song and image titles to the lock screen?

Answer (score 1):

I've forked the cordova-media-plugin so that when you create a new Media object, you can pass in metadata in the options object.

The plugin, along with an example project, is available here:

https://github.com/adeeshaek/cordova-plugin-media